# Problems keeping track of loop index in recursion

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

Hello im working on assembly, my problem is the following i need to know if there is a way of keeping track of some variables in assembly while using recursion. I know i can use the stack to pass parameters to the recursive function when i call it. For example this code in python:

```
def topologicalSort(node):
    lista = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
    size = 4
    order = []
    for i in range(size):
        if lista[node*size+i] == 1 and (i+1) not in order:
            return topologicalSort(i)

    order.append(node+1) #node starts in 1
```

I know its not complete, but what i want to do for example is having called the function 2 times I need that when i return the function I still keep track of the index "i" in the for loop.
In assembly y do in just using `JMP` and iterating the number of times i need using a register. So when `RET` is called I loose the counter's value(in this case i).

Comment: I don't know python, so I have dumb question: Is `lista` local (i.e. defined every time you enter `topologicalSort`, or it's static/global variable (only one copy per call)? BTW, just as you can use stack to pass parameters, you can also store values there. (just make sure you pop them ahead of ret to restore the stack) It's how C usually works, putting local function variables into stack space.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save/restore any local state across a function call (recursive or not).  Either push/pop the valuable data, or push/pop a call-saved register (e.g. BX depending on your calling convention) and keep your state data in that.